# ask cli generates language models many languages, how can I just do en-US?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I created a project using the ask cli as follows:

```
ask new --skill-name my-new-skill
```

It created a number of language models in `models`. I deleted all but, `en-US.json` and ran:

```
ask deploy
```

However in the Alexa developer console, I see language models created for German, variations of English, Hindi etc. How can I tell the ask cli I only want `en-US` at this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Remove the entries from `skill.json`